# Printing a UTF char by its non-ASCII code in Python

Tags: python, utf-8

I want to print a non-ASCII (UTF-8) by its code rather than the character itself using Python 2.7.

For example, I have the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print "…"
```

and that's OK. However, I want to print '…' using '\xe2', the corresponding code, instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

printing `'\xe2\x80\xa6'` will give you `...`

```
In [36]: print'\xe2\x80\xa6'
…

In [45]: print repr("…")
'\xe2\x80\xa6'
```

Comment: You found this using repr?

Comment: @erip, yes.  when your print you see the str representation.